# SQL Server: Count grouping by user and date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

In my SQL Server 2008 i got a table that stores `datetime` of every users' actions. It looks something like this:

```
id  |  username   |   action  |  actionDate
------------------------------------
1   |  bob        |   add     |  2015-08-15 11:20:12
2   |  bob        |   add     |  2015-08-15 11:21:52
3   |  sandra     |   add     |  2015-08-15 11:25:32
4   |  sandra     |   add     |  2015-08-15 11:26:32
5   |  bob        |   add     |  2015-08-15 11:31:52
6   |  sandra     |   add     |  2015-08-16 13:46:32
7   |  sandra     |   add     |  2015-08-16 13:26:32
8   |  bob        |   add     |  2015-08-16 13:31:52
9   |  sandra     |   add     |  2015-08-16 13:46:32
```

This table rather big and stores data for many-many days. So i need to get how many times each user made action "add" for every day. e.g.:

```
actionDate   |  username   |   countRow
2015-08-15   |  bob        |   3
2015-08-15   |  sandra     |   2
2015-08-16   |  bob        |   2
2015-08-16   |  sandra     |   3
```

I've tried a lot of different queries, but I still can't get it. The closest query I think looks like this:

```
SELECT S.username, S.actionDate, C.countRow
    From dbo.actionTable S
    INNER JOIN( SELECT Convert(date, actionDate),count(username) as countRow
                FROM dbo.actionTable
                WHERE action = 'add'
                GROUP BY Convert(date, actionDate)) C ON S.actionDate = C.actionDate
```

but this query returns me too much wrong data. Please, tell me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't do it directly ..

```
select 
  username
  ,convert(date,actionDate) as actionDate
  ,count(*) as countRow
from actionTable
where action = 'add'
group by username
         ,convert(date,actionDate)
```

Comment: one more question on this query. actionTable has much more cols - 28. Only some of them has indexes. Won't count(*) be very slow? is it possible to count not by all cols?

Comment: There is no problem. Count(*) will just count rows. You can use count(1) or count(oneColumn) or count(*). It will just do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select convert(date,actionDate) actionDate, username, 
count(*) coutntRow from actionTable 
where action   = 'add'
group by convert(date,actionDate), userName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.username,  Convert(date, S.actionDate), count(S.id) as  countRow,S.action
From dbo.actionTable S  WHERE S.action = 'add' 
GROUP BY Convert(date, S.actionDate),S.action,S.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I recommend you the normalization of your database.

If I were you I do this: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table name: **userTable**
------------------------------------
id |  username 
------------------------------------
1  | bob        
2  | sandra 
3  | peter
++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table name: **actionTable**
------------------------------------
id | action
------------------------------------
1  | add
2  | update
3  | delete 
++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table name: **actionUser**
------------------------------------
ID  | user_id  | action_id |  actionDate
------------------------------------
| 1 |  1       |   1       | 2015-08-15 11:20:12
| 2 |  2       |   2       | 2015-08-15 11:21:52
| 3 |  1       |   1       | 2015-08-15 11:25:32
```

This is a better architecture for this problem.

And the query should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id)
FROM dbo.actionUser
WHERE user_id = %
```

where % is the ID of your user.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you. but it's not mine database. i have no access to manage it. I just have to use that table and it's much more complicated. but thanks for advice